# Calling C functions that take nested structures (by reference) in J

Tags: c, struct, shared-libraries, pass-by-reference, j

I am learning how to call shared libraries in J. I have read the succinct tutorial on [DLLs and Memory Management](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/user/dlls.htm) and also [chapter 21](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/jforc/calling_external_programs.htm) of [J for C Programmers](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/jforc/contents.htm).

In C, I defined the following `struct`:

```
typedef struct {
    int    type;
    double rate;
    double quantity;
} Order;
```

Still in C, I then defined functions `getType`, `getRate` and `getQuant` that take a `struct` of type `Order` and return its `type`, `rate` and `quantity`, respectively. Lastly, I did build a shared library (shared object) `test.so`.

In J, I created an `ijs` file containing the following:

```
DLL =: jpath '/Users/rodrigo/Desktop/test.so'

cd=: 15!:0

NB. int getType(Order order)
getType =: 3 : 0
 cmd =. DLL,' getType i i d d'
 1 pick cmd cd y
)

NB. double getRate(Order order)
getRate =: 3 : 0
 cmd =. DLL,' getRate d i d d'
 2 pick cmd cd y
)

NB. double getQuant(Order order)
getQuant =: 3 : 0
 cmd =. DLL,' getQuant d i d d'
 3 pick cmd cd y
)
```

Testing these simple test functions in `jqt`:

```
   order1 =: 1; 2.2; 3.3
   order2 =: 4; 5.5; 6.6

   (getType order1); (getRate order1); (getQuant order1)
┌─┬───┬───┐
│1│2.2│3.3│
└─┴───┴───┘
   (getType order2); (getRate order2); (getQuant order2)
┌─┬───┬───┐
│4│5.5│6.6│
└─┴───┴───┘
```

So far, so good. However, in C, I have also defined the following `struct` that contains a member of type array of `Order`s:

```
typedef struct {
    long    number;
    Order   buys[10];
} Block;
```

Still in C, I defined a function that takes a string and passes a `struct` of type `Block` by reference:

```
int parser(const char *str, Block *blck);
```

My questions are the following:

1. How can I call this parsing function in J? What descriptors should I use?
2. Must I use memory management, i.e., functions `mema`, `memf`, `memr` and `memw`? If so, how?
3. The tutorials I read do not have examples with `struct`s. Could you please provide pointers to J code in which C functions that take addresses of `struct`s containing nested `struct`s are called from J via the use of a shared library?

---

**Compensation:** bounty of at least 200 points to whoever answers (most) satisfactorily.

Comment: I haven't seen the people who could answer your question frequenting stackoverflow. Perhaps head over to the J programming forum and then post your question. When you get the answer that you want you can back here for the benefit of stackoverflow participants. http://www.jsoftware.com/forums.htm  is the link to forums and I think programming is most likely the forum that fits your question.